# I added two fields on table and now insertion won't work

Tags: php, mysql

Happy New Year folks.  I'm a newbie and apparently a simpleton.  I had an HTML entry form for a movie database that's been working fine.  I decided to add two fields to the data base (`720` and `1080`.)  That's all I did, honest.  But now it won't write and I get the dreaded Error X.  I've been going over the code for hours and can't find what I did wrong.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
//  Write data to table.    

 $sql="INSERT INTO movies (Movies, Rating, Genre, Year, Actors, Time, Notes, Viewed, link, 720, 1080)
    VALUES ('" . $_POST['Movies'] . "', '" . $_POST['Rating'] . "', '" . $_POST['Genre'] . "', '" . $_POST['Year'] . "', '" . $_POST['Actors'] . "', '" . $_POST['Time'] . "', '" . $_POST['Notes'] . "', '" . $_POST['Viewed'] . "', '{$f_link}', '" . $_POST['720'] . "', '" . $_POST['1080'] . "')";

 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
 die('Error: X ' . mysql_error($con));
  }

 echo "<center>1 record successfully added</center>";

    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: And the rest of the error message is...? Maybe if you used `mysqli_error` instead of the wrong `mysql_error` you'd know.

Comment: is `link` not named `Link` which would follow the casing pattern?

Comment: Not related to your question, but concatenating $_POST-variables directly into your query is a very, very easy way to get your website compromised/hacked. You should try reading [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com/) to see why, and how you can prevent it.

Comment: Thank you folks.  It would appear that you have solved my issue.  It did cross my mind that maybe I couldn't just numbers for a field.  I'm sure once I change those it will work. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Set Sail Media you are right.  I'm not only a newbie but a hack.  When I added the link field I didn't stay consistent and I just left it that way.  I guess I should fix that.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian Paaske Torholm.  I will surely look into that.  The book I bought from "Head First" (O'Reilly) told me to use the $_Post.  I'll definitely look into your suggestion.  Every time I screw up one thing and come here I learn a ton more.

Answer (score 4):

From the Mysql documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

**Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.**

Answer (score 2):

Escaping column names with backticks works, so use `` `720` ``, `` `1080` `` instead.

On a sidenote, you should cleanup and escape `$_POST` data before insert.

Also, I think you have to use `mysqli_error()` instead of `mysql_error()`.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, thanks again for all your help.  I had to hit the grocery store before the two day, foot of snow storm that's coming in around midnight.

I changed the names to R720 and R1080 (for resolution) and that solved the problem.  Unfortunately, and I have no idea why, if I try to use the mysql instead of the mysqli I get the error message.  And it has never actually given me the code.  Just Error X.

I did take a peek at the slide show at bobby-tales but it's a bit much for me right now.  I will look into it in the next few days and try and understand it.

Again, thanks and have a Happy New Year.

Comment: For the security issue, you may like to read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). This is a serious threat, and every programmer must practice SQL injection defense before deploying their apps on the public web. Here's another resource that might help, it's a presentation I created: [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies)